# Scala: How to extend an Akka actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I wrote an Akka base-actor that can handle some common messages. I want to reuse this basic behavior in a sub-actor, by extending the base-actor (not by composition of the base-actor).

I have seen several approaches in previous questions. They are all valid but also may be improved:

[How extend behaviour of super actor in akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483869/how-extend-behaviour-of-super-actor-in-akka)

and

[How do I best share behavior among Akka actors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383827/how-do-i-best-share-behavior-among-akka-actors)

To make the implementation cleaner, I am trying to achieve the following:

- When defining the sub-actor, I try to extend only the base-actor (not both `Actor` and `sub-actor`). However, I was not able to force the compiler to do this.
- I also try to not rename the `receive` partial function, because it is a kind of convention.

**Here is a sample of my implementation:**

```
//This is the base-actor that implements the common behavior

trait BetterActor extends Actor {

  abstract override def receive = {
    super.receive orElse { case _ => println("Missing pattern!") }
  }
}

//This is the actor that implements the additional behavior.
//I actually wanted to extend BetterActor. It was not possible.

class MyActor extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case i: Int =>
      println(s"Yay!!! Got $i")
  }
}
```

**Here are two alternative ways how I can create an instance of the sub-actor, which combines both the common and the additional behaviors:**

```
//1.

val myBetterActor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor with BetterActor), "myBetterActor")

//2.

class MyBetterActor extends MyActor with BetterActor
val myBetterActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyBetterActor], "myBetterActor")
```

**Finally, I may invoke the sub-actor by:**

```
myBetterActor ! 2
myBetterActor ! "a"
```

**Problems with my implementation:**

When I create an instance of the sub-actor, only then I can mix in the base-actor, either directly (1) or by defining a new class that mixes in the base-actor.

Like I said before, I would prefer to mix in the base-actor when I define the sub-actor. Not when I try to create an instance of the sub-actor.

**P.S.** It's fascinating that the designers of this framework did not see it necessary to make this common requirement easy to accomplish.

Comment: Designers of this framework have created the `unhandled` method in `Actor` - it may be enough for you to simply override it

Comment: @ghik I don't understand your one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose as long as you're not trying to *override* behavior with BetterActor, you could try something like this:

```
trait BetterActor extends Actor {
  override def unhandled(message: Any): Unit = message match {
    case e: CommonMessage => println("COMMON!")
    case e => super.unhandled(e)
  }
}

class MyActor extends BetterActor {
  override def receive = {
    case i: Int => println(s"Yay!!! Got $i")
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it compile? I think you mean `unhandled(message: Any): Unit = { message match {...} }`

Comment: It is also not required to `override` the `def receive`. Also, like you said, `receive` will override the `unhandled` in the base actor. It actually makes sense to have it this way. It is a good solution. Thank you.

Comment: @rapt oops, i'm so clumsy. yes you're right about the missing match.  i'll edit the answer to reflect that.